# Problema com strcpy

Tags: c, string

Eu estou tentando preencher os campos de uma `struct` com `strcpy` mas não estou obtendo o valor esperado, como por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Aluno {
    char tipo;
    char matricula[8];
    char idade[2];
    char nome[40];
};

int main( )
{

    struct Aluno m;

    m.tipo = '5';
    strcpy(m.matricula, "20101122");
    strcpy(m.idade, "30");
    strcpy(m.nome, "Jack Revoltado");

    printf(" Tipo do aluno = %c\n",m.tipo);
    printf(" matricula %s\n",m.matricula);
    printf(" tamanho %s\n",m.idade);
    printf(" nome %s\n",m.nome);

    return 0;
}
```

Cuja saida é :

```
Tipo do aluno = 5
 matricula 2010112230Jack Revoltado
 tamanho 30Jack Revoltado
 nome Jack Revoltado
```

Ou seja, a função está concatenando tudo e obviamente que eu não quero isso. Por que essa função está fazendo isso se eu não passei do limite do espaço destinado a cada campo? E o que deve ser feito para que cada campo tenha seu respectivo valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C as strings precisam ter um zero binário ao final.Então, sua estrutura precisa reservar espaço para ese zero binário. Portanto sua estrutura deve ser declarada assim:

```
struct Aluno
{
  char tipo;
  char matricula[9]; // <---
  char idade[3];     // <---
  char nome[41];     // <---
};
```